# Determine the source of the API request from which it is coming from?

Tags: django, google-chrome, postman

How can I determine the source of the request?

I am using django.

For example, if I send a request from POSTMAN to some API like `http://example/api/`, I need to get POSTMAN as an answer.

If I do the same from Chrome, I need to get Chrome as an answer.

Comment: Usually this data is present in the request.META for django. Try printing request.META in your dev environment for an api hit.

Comment: Thank you, Mehran. It worked.